# PHP Warning: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, implode

I have this code in my file:

```
if (is_array($_REQUEST))
   $cepl=implode(' ', $_REQUEST);
```

every couple of days I get this warning in php log:
PHP Warning:  Array to string conversion in /file.php on line 76

line 76 is:   $cepl=implode(' ', $_REQUEST);

I can't find out what is causing  this warning?!

Comment: Which line is line 76?  When the error occurs, what is the observed value of the variables used on that line?

Comment: We cannot find it either. Because we don't have access to your computer

Comment: Assuming line 76 is the second line in your question, you'll see that error if one of the **values** in `$_REQUEST` is an array

Comment: @iainn isn't "$_REQUEST" an array?! and yes the 76 is the second line

Comment: Yes it's an array. But take note of the bold text in iainn's comment. It's bold for a reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the `implode` function is *very roughly* equivalent to this (this is just an illustration, not tested code):

```
function not_really_implode($glue, $pieces) {
   $result = '';
   $first = true;
   foreach ( $pieces as $piece ) {
      if ( ! $first ) {
          $result .= $glue;
      }
      $pieceAsString = (string)$piece;
      $result .= $pieceAsString;
      $first = false;
   }
   return $result;
}
```

The key point is the line `$pieceAsString = (string)$piece;` - in order to combine the elements of the array, `implode` has to convert *each of them in turn* to strings.

Now consider what happens if `$pieces` looks like this:

```
$pieces = [
   'one',
   ['two-a', 'two-b'],
   'three',
];
```

At some point in our loop, we're going to have `$piece = ['two-a', 'two-b']`, and try to convert it to a string - whoops!

So, the warning comes about because *inside* your `$_REQUEST` array, there are other arrays. There's a couple of ways this can happen:

1. `$_REQUEST` can be written to directly. For instance, someone can write `$_REQUEST['example'] = ['a', 'b'];`
2. PHP [recognises certain notations in input](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) to mean arrays. For instance, someone can visit the url `/your-page.php?example[]=a&example[]=b` and `$_REQUEST` will automatically be populated with `['a', 'b']`.

This leads to a very important reminder: **Never trust user input!** Making *any* assumptions about what's in `$_REQUEST` is very dangerous, because *that input is under the user's control*, and the user might not be your friend.